# CUPS webservice does not ask for authentication in Chrome

Tags: printing, google-chrome

When accessing http://localhost:631/printers/ in Firefox and selecting particular printer, then Administration->Modify Printer, the Firefox provides username and password popup. In Chrome, the webservice does not show the popup at all and goes straight to the error page:

> Unauthorized 
>   Enter your username and password or the root username and
>   password to access this page. If you are using Kerberos
>   authentication, make sure you have a valid Kerberos ticket.

I am in `lpadmin` group. How do I make Chrome behave properly with CUPS webservice?